# Delete before delete trigger

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables:

Table MASTER
Table SLAVE with a column ID that always matches a MASTER.ID

I would like to delete the SLAVE before deleting a MASTER through a DB2 trigger.
Here's what I wrote:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_slave
BEFORE DELETE ON MASTER
REFERENCING OLD AS o FOR EACH ROW 
DELETE FROM SLAVE WHERE ID = o.ID;
```

When I execute the query on a DB2 V10.5.0.3 database I get the following error:

> The trigger "SCHEMA1.DELETE_SLAVE" is defined with an unsupported
>   triggered SQL statement.. SQLCODE=-797, SQLSTATE=42987, DRIVER=4.17.29
>   SQL Code: -797, SQL State: 42987

Could someone help me to identify what's wrong in the SQL statement that's triggered ?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Try `...FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM SLAVE WHERE...; END`

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer,

According to http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html:

> The SQL-procedure-statement in a BEFORE trigger cannot: Contain any
>   INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE operations, nor invoke any routine defined
>   with MODIFIES SQL DATA, if it is not a compound SQL (compiled).